# How do I change the icon of a cell on the factory monitor?

Tags: moryx

I want to change the icon of a cell on the factory monitor, but don't know how. It is always settings.

I created a resource

```
[ResourceRegistration]
public class AssemblyCell: Cell
{
   ...
   
   [EntrySerialize, DataMember]
   public int Value {get;set;}

   [EntrySerialize, DataMember]
   public int TestParameter {get;set;}
}
```

Then I created a MachineLocation in the UI and added my AssemblyCell as a child. The cell appears in the factory monitor with the icon settings. Now I want to change this icon. Am I missing some kind of attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **Factory Monitor UI**, click on the **cell** (big white circle with **settings** **icon** on it). When you click on the cell, a **details view** will appear on **top right corner**.
In that **details view** there is an **icon** right before the **name of the cell**. **Click** on that **icon**. You will see a new **form dialog** appear on the screen. There is an **icon** on the new dialog, on the **top left corner** right next to  the **name of the cell**. Click on the icon and you should see the icon editor appear. You can now change the icon name and click on **save**.